# how to find the place where a Thread was started from a breakpoint

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

This is my situation:

- I am studying a large codebase, running on Java1.7, not very easy to move around, lots of interfaces, deep inheritance trees, lots of threads etc.
- I put a breakpoint in some place, but this object is running in a Thread that was spawned somewhere. I need to find that place.
- there are too many .run() and .start() hits to look for individually (and to narrow down by the class is difficult too as there are many classes/inheritance (and I don't know the codebase yet)).

So my questions is, is there a way, having a Thread stopped in a breakpoint (intelliJ, but I can use eclipse too) to find out where it was started??

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

I don't think there's a way out of this without some brute force effort.

I would trace back to the Runnable that was started (through the stack trace), then get that class' inheritance and interface hierarchy, then look for run() and start() methods on all those classes.  Unless someone has just gone nuts with inheritance, it shouldn't take that long.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can put breakpoint into `Thread.start()`.

To avoid mutltiple invocation of breakpoint, maybe it make sense to place breakpoint with conditional logic, for example checking global boolean flag. For example, you suspect, that your code invokes right before some event, when event happens, put global flag to true.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking on the code in your object tells you which thread it is and its call stack can tell you which `Runnable` you should be looking for. I'm assuming you've already gotten this far and that it's not enough to find all the references to this Thread/Runnable. In that case you can write a wrapper class for `java.lang.Thread` that does an instanceof/type check in the `run()` and setting your breakpoint there

Answer (score 0):

I think first you have to get the `Runnable` that is run. That's simple as it's always the first line of your stack trace. (Of course you need the concrete class and not the one that defines the run method.) Once you have the class it should be easy to find the instantiation. Then it should simple to follow to the point where the thread is started. Did I miss something?